# CRC32 C++ implementation using bool array and manually XORing bit by bit

Tags: c++, xor, crc, crc32

I have problem with understanding how CRC32 should work in normal way. 
I've implemented mechanism from wiki and other sites: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Computation
where you xor elements bit by bit.  
For CRC32 I've used Polynomial from wiki, which is also everywhere:

```
x^32 + x^26 + x^23 + x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
with binary representation: 1 0000 0100 1100 0001 0001 1101 1011 0111
```

I was calculating CRC32 for input string "1234" only for testing.
This is the output of program: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG4wk.png
as you can see the xor is calculated properly and CRC32 is "619119D1". 
 When I calculate it using online calculator or even c++ boost lib, the answer is "9BE3E0A3". 
What is wrong with normal XORing input string bit by bit? Should I add something at the end or what?
I don't want to use libs and any other magic code to compute this, because I have to implement it in that way for my study project.
I've tried also polynomial without x^32, negate bits at the end, starting from 1s instead of 0s (where you have to add 32 zeros), and the answer is also different. I have no idea what should I do now to fix this.
This is the part of the code (a bit changed), I have buffor 3parts * 32bits, I'm loading 4 Chars from file to the middle part and xor from beggining to the middle, at the end I xor the middle part and the end -> the end is CRC32.

```
My pseudo schema:
1) Load 8 chars
2) | First part | Middle Part | CRC32 = 0 |
3) XOR
4) | 0 0 0 0 | XXXXXXX | 0 0 0 0 |
5) memcpy - middle part to first part
6) | XXXXXXX | XXXXXXX | 0 0 0 0  |
7) Load 4 chars
8) | XXXXXXX | loaded 4chars | 0 0 0 0 |
9) repeat from point 4 to the end of file
10) now we have: | 0 0 0 0 | XXXXXX | 0 0 0 0 |
11) last xor from middle part to end
12) Result: | 0 0 0 0 |  0 0 0 0 | CRC32 |
```

Probably screen with output will be more helpful. 
I will use smart pointers etc. later ;)

```
bool xorBuffer(unsigned char *buffer) {
    bool * binaryTab = nullptr;
    try {
        // CRC-32
        // 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00
        //  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1
        const int dividerSizeBits = 33;
        const bool binaryDivider[dividerSizeBits] = { 1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1 };

        const int dividerLength = countLength(binaryDivider, dividerSizeBits);
        const int dividerOffset = dividerSizeBits - dividerLength;  // when divider < 33 bits

        bool * binaryTab = charTabToBits(buffer);

        // check tab if first part = 0
        while (!checkTabIfEmpty(binaryTab)) {
            // set the beginnning
            int start = 0;
            for (start = 0; start < 32; start++)
                if (binaryTab[start] == true)
                    break;
            for (int i = 0; i < dividerLength; i++)
                binaryTab[i + start] = binaryTab[i + start] ^ binaryDivider[i + dividerOffset];    
        }
        // binaryTab -> charTab
        convertBinaryTabToCharTab(binaryTab, buffer);
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        delete[] binaryTab;
        return false;
    }
    delete[] binaryTab;
    return true;
}

std::string CRC::countCRC(std::string fileName){
    // create variables
    int bufferOnePartSize = 4;
    int bufferSize = bufferOnePartSize * 3;
    bool EOFFlag = false;
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 * bufferOnePartSize; i++)
        buffer[i] = 0;

    // open file
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str(), ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

    int position = 0;
    int count = 0;
    // while -> EOF
    if (fin.is_open()) {
        // TODO check if file <= 4 -> another solution
        char ch;
        int multiply = 2;
        bool skipNormalXor = false;
        while (true) {
            count = 0;
            if (multiply == 2)
                position = 0;
            else
                position = bufferOnePartSize;
            // copy part form file to tab
            while (count < bufferOnePartSize * multiply && fin.get(ch)) {
                buffer[position] = (unsigned char)ch;
                ++count;
                ++position;
            }
            cout << endl;
            // if EOF write zeros to end of tab
            if (count == 0) {
                cout << "TODO: end of file" << endl;
                EOFFlag = true;
                skipNormalXor = true;
            }
            else if (count != bufferOnePartSize * multiply) {
                for (int i = count; i < bufferOnePartSize * multiply; i++) {
                    buffer[position] = 0;
                    position++;
                }
                EOFFlag = true;
            }

            if (!skipNormalXor) {
                // -- first part
                multiply = 1;
                // xor the buffer
                xorBuffer(buffer);
            }

            if (EOFFlag) {  // xor to the end
                xorBuffer(buffer + bufferOnePartSize);
                break;
            }
            else {
                // copy memory
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferOnePartSize; i++)
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i + bufferOnePartSize];
            }
        }
        cout << "\n End\n";
        fin.close();
    }

    stringstream crcSum;
    for (int i = 2 * bufferOnePartSize; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        //buffer[i] = ~buffer[i];
        crcSum << std::hex << (unsigned int)buffer[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "CRC: " << crcSum.str() << endl;
    delete[] buffer;
    return crcSum.str();
}
```

Comment: Standard crc32 calculation begins with value of 0xffffffff not 0. Then at end invert all bits by xor with 0xffffffff.

Answer (score 3):

A CRC is not defined by just the polynomial. You need to define the bit ordering, the initial value of the CRC register, and the final exclusive-or of the CRC. For the standard CRC-32, which gives 0x9be3e0a3 for "1234", the bits are processed starting with the least significant bit, the initial value of the register is `0xffffffff`, and you exclusive-or the final results with `0xffffffff`.

Comment: Yeah, so why can't I do it as it is on wiki? I'm calculating it as normally on paper. If I put 1s instead of 0s in the initial value and xored it at the end with 0xffffffff, which is just negating bits, then I will get different value. I don't care about little and big-endian, because I xor it manually in bool array convertering chars to bits manually, as it is on screenshot. I tired a lot ideas in the past 2 days, and I've decided finally to give up and write on stack.

Comment: The bit ordering has nothing to do with big or little endian. It has to do with which bit in the data is the first bit you start applying the CRC calculation to. Is it the low bit of the first byte, or the high bit of the first byte?

Comment: I simply convert ASCII string "1234" to bits {49,50,51,52}(10) = {31,32,33,34}(16) =  0011 0001 0011 0010 0011 0011 0011 0100 (2). And then xor it with polynomial from left to right, so I start from high bit of the first byte. This is good visible on attached screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG4wk.png . Should I reflect each byte before it is being processed or should I reflect all input file to process bits from the end ("4321")?

Comment: To match the standard CRC-32, you need to start with the low bit. You can reflect the input bytes to do that, though better is to reflect the polynomial, since you only have to do that once. You still do the bytes in order (1, 2, 3, 4).